# Saving Profile model after update: IntegrityError (duplicate user_id key)

Tags: django, forms, user-profile

My Django site has two sorts of user profiles, one for regular users (`MyUserProfile`) and one, which extends it, for employees (`EmployeeUserProfile`). `models.py`:

```
class MyUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.user', related_name='userprofile')
    www = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='website')
    affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    ...

class EmployeeUserProfile(MyUserProfile):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    current = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

I have a problem implementing an profile update form for employees. I create the form thus (`forms.py`):

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import EmployeeUserProfile

class EmployeeUserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeUserProfile
        exclude = ['user', 'current']
```

But when I come to updating the profile:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import EmployeeUserProfileForm

def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
    else:
        user = request.user
        profile = user.userprofile.employeeuserprofile
        form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(instance=profile)
    c = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('pages/profile/update.html', c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

On 'submit' for updating an already-created profile I get an `IntegrityError`. For example, `(1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'user_id'")`. Apparently Django is trying to add a copy of the user instead of updating the existing one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the instance argument in the `POST` condition too

```
form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(request.POST)
```

should be

```
form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
```

[By  not sending the `instance` argument, form tries to `create` instead of `update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).  Note that this would mean you would have to move the `else` block above `if`

Something like this:

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):

    user = request.user
    profile = user.userprofile.employeeuserprofile
    form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(instance=profile)

   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeUserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()

    c = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('pages/profile/update.html', c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You might also want to use the `login_required` decorator so that you dont run into issues with anonymous user, etc..

Comment: Doh! I feel stupid now. Thank you-- that's what was wrong. (I do have `login_required`).